# Can i add different assets for each build variant using Play Asset Delivery ( Android Studio)?

Tags: java, android

I need to add different assets for each build variants in Android Studio and i'm trying  to use  Play Asset Delivery, unfortunately there its no documentation or at least i could not find it . Its this even possible ?

My plan its to replace the "old" delivery system of assets using obb , and its an app not a game .

Comment: Hi. Did you ever find a solution to this? We're facing the same issue, and there's basically zero info about it. Thanks

Comment: Nope ... I just comment out the assets packs that i don't need

Comment: Thanks for replying

Answer (score 3):

Incredibly it seems like there's no way to set the `assetPacks` per flavor in build.gradle!

We have a lot of assetPacks, and a bunch of flavors, so we added a map that maps flavor name to `assetPacks`, and set `assetPacks` from that.

From our build.gradle:

```
// figure out what our current flavor is to use to set the asset packs
Gradle gradle = getGradle()
String  tskReqStr = gradle.getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString()
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Z][a-z]+)(Release|Debug)")
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( tskReqStr )
String currentflavor = ""
if( matcher.find() )
    currentflavor = matcher.group(1).toLowerCase()

if ( AssetPacks[currentflavor] ) {
    assetPacks = AssetPacks[currentflavor]
    // sanity check
    println AssetPacks[currentflavor]
}
else if ( currentflavor ) {
    // sanity check
    println "NO ASSET PACKS"
}
```